# Is there any way to get same result from "AVERAGE" function(excel) and "MEAN" function(R)?

Tags: r, excel, average, rounding, mean

I am comparing two 'mean'(or average) calculation results, calculated by excel and R respectively,
I found out that results is different under 4th decimal points.

I am trying to figure out the reason,
and I found out that
R rounds the summed value to 4th decimal places.

Is there any way to make R NOT to rounds the value?

Thank you.

Comment: Is R rounding the value or is R displaying the value rounded but storing it correctly?  Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I don't believe R actually rounds the value, it just limits how many decimal places it prints. You can change this using e.g. `options(digits = 10)` in the console. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025679/sum-of-column-rounds-decimals

Answer (score 0):

You can try this when printing the result (assuming it's numeric double)

```
print(result, digits=5)
```